# Property 'section 1' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'. aot build

Tags: angular, angular-aot

When I take aot build in angular I got an error Property 'section 1' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'. I had added

```
<form [formGroup]="currentMonthForm" novalidate>
<table class="table spinwheel-table-blk">
      <thead>
        <tr COLSPAN=2 class="spinwheel-table-heading-block">
          <th>Section ID</th>
          <th><span>Points</span></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr COLSPAN=2>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>
            <div class="input-group wingsclub-inputgroup">
              <input type="text" class="form-control validation-field" placeholder="Points" aria-label="Recipient's username"
                aria-describedby="basic-addon2" maxlength="3" formControlName="section1" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': currentMonthForm.section1 }"
                (input)="section1Change(1)">
              <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="sectionFormErrors.section1">
                <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="sectionFormErrors.section1">{{sectionFormErrors.section1}}</small>
              </small>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
<table>
```

and in component I had

```
currentMonthForm: FormGroup;
constructor(){
this.buildForm();
}
    buildForm() {
        this.currentMonthForm = this.fb.group({
          section1: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(3),
          CustomValidators.number, this.validateNumber, CustomValidatorsInUse.isInteger, CustomValidatorsInUse.isPositiveInteger,])],})
```

But I get error Property 'section 1' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'. in aot build. But in general build its working correctly.

Comment: Can you show the whole component here?
There are some things that don't always work with AoT , until specified properly. Is the `section1` property `protected` or `private`?

Comment: what is the type of `sectionFormErrors`?

Comment: sectionFormErrors is just a object which is used to map errors

Comment: section1 is just fromcontrol value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the culprit is this:

```
[ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': currentMonthForm.section1 }"
```

JIT compiler doesn't check whether the property really exist on the object, but AOT build does and it complains that `currentMonthForm` FormGroup doesn't have that property.
You should fix the condition for `is-invalid` class as it is very strange currently. I would expect something like:

```
[ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': currentMonthForm.get('section1').errors !== null }"
```

Comment: Yes, That was the problem.